# Select all Checkboxes with single selection of checkbox in angular5 using angular material

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

am written code like this in HTML:

```
<table class="table tableWidths shadowTable">
      <thead>
        <tr class="tableHeaderBgColor">
          <th>
            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Conflict ID</th>
          <th>Conflict Party</th>
          <th>Conflict Party ID</th>
          <th>Account Name</th>
          <th>Account Owner Name</th>
          <th>Account Owner ID</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let conf of conflicts;let ns=index;let odd=odd;">
          <tr [class.tableOdd]="odd">
            <td>
              <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(conf) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(conf)">
              </mat-checkbox>
            </td>
            <td>{{conf.Status}}</td>
            <td>
              {{conf.Conflict_ID}}
            </td>
            <td>{{conf.Conflict_Party}}</td>
            <td>{{conf.Conflict_Party_ID}}</td>
            <td>{{conf.Account_Name}}</td>
            <td>{{conf.Account_Owner_Name}}</td>
            <td>{{conf.Account_Owner_ID}}</td>
            <td>
              <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

in .ts file code wrote like this:

```
conflicts = [
    {
      Status: 'Pending',
      Conflict_ID: 203888400,
      Conflict_Party: 'Collier County Pulish',
      Conflict_Party_ID: 12345,
      Account_Name: 'Asian Group LD',
      Account_Owner_Name: 'Mike',
      Account_Owner_ID: 12345, checked: false
    },
    {
      Status: 'Approved',
      Conflict_ID: 203888400,
      Conflict_Party: 'Collier County Pulish',
      Conflict_Party_ID: 12345,
      Account_Name: 'Asian Group LD',
      Account_Owner_Name: 'Mary',
      Account_Owner_ID: 12345, checked: false
    }
  ]    
isAllSelected() {
        const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
        const numRows = this.conflicts.length;
        return numSelected === numRows;
      }

      masterToggle() {
        this.isAllSelected() ?
          this.selection.clear() :
          this.conflicts.forEach(row => this.selection.select());
      }
      isSelected(item) {
        console.log('item ' + JSON.stringify(item));
      }
```

In my array Conflict ID is the value to getting further processing. Whenever selection done get the key value from this key 'Conflict_ID'.
Here am unable to select all checkboxes at single selection in the table. 
I am able to de-select the all checkboxes.
Can anybody suggest some solution for this.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong. What you want is that when you select the master checkbox all the check boxes should be selected and vice-versa.

Comment: You haven't shown code for `selection.hasValue()`, `selection.toggle()`, or the structure of the `selection` object.

Comment: Also - you are binding `[checked]="selection.isSelected(conf)"` but that function does not have a return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a sample for Angular material check boxes with select all option. See the [Working version in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-checkbox-demo). Hope it will help

component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Configurable checkbox
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-configurable-example',
  templateUrl: 'checkbox-configurable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['checkbox-configurable-example.css'],
})
export class CheckboxConfigurableExample {
  pizzaIng : any;
  selectAll = false;

  constructor(){
    this.pizzaIng=[
      {name : "Pepperoni", checked : false},
      {name : "Sasuage", checked : true},
      {name : "Mushrooms", checked : false}
    ];
  }

  updateCheck(){
    console.log(this.selectAll);
    if(this.selectAll === true){
      this.pizzaIng.map((pizza)=>{
        pizza.checked=true;
      });

    }else {
      this.pizzaIng.map((pizza)=>{
        pizza.checked=false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<mat-card class="result">
  <mat-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Sample</h2>

    <section *ngFor="let ing of pizzaIng; let i = index" class="example-section">
      <mat-checkbox
         [(ngModel)]="ing.checked">
        {{ing.name}}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </section>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>


<mat-card class="result">
  <mat-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Select / Deselect</h2>

    <section class="example-section">
      <mat-checkbox (change)="updateCheck()"
          class="example-margin"
          [(ngModel)]="selectAll">
        Select All
      </mat-checkbox>
    </section>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here array contains 'checked' key but, in my array there is no availability.

Comment: How will your array look like? selection.hasValue() is not defined in your shared code. Share the complete code or working version in stackblitz. Try to add checked key in your JSON format or your code will become more complex.

Comment: Edited my question in '.ts' file code please check it. when checked any checkbox get the value of an key as 'Conflict_ID'.

Comment: Not working, Instead of adding checked key in my JSON, is there any another way to solve this issue. Am asking this.

Comment: use ngModel and do like the example shared. it will work